# perfomSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone: randomly stops working

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsthread, nsoperationqueue

I'm running a selector on the background thread then I need to call the main thread and it works perfectly, but when there are a lot of selectors running on the background and they try to call a selector on the main thread sometimes it gets called, sometimes it doesn't. I can see the code is getting there because I'm printing with NSLog();

This is how I call the selector on the background:

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];
NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]
                                        initWithTarget:self
                                        selector:@selector(getPath:)
                                        object:datos];
[queue addOperation:operation];
[operation release];
```

And this is how the background method calls the main thread method:

```
NSLog(@"Arrives here");
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setPath:) withObject:array waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Why does it sometimes work, and sometimes it doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

How do you know it doesn't work?

Is there anything blocking your main thread?    A modal session, per chance?

Note that "a lot of selectors running on the background" sounds scary;  un-throttled concurrency is pretty much guaranteed to be the wrong answer.    It is quite easy to create a system that storms the main event loop with so much noise that it looks like events are being dropped.

Comment: I fixed it, it indeed wasn't being called, I don't know why, but I did it like this:

    `dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create(@"some_name", NULL);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            //Heavy code goes here
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //Heavy code is done
        });
    });
    dispatch_release(queue);`